# unable to update the list value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch products from my razorpay account but am facing issues the values get printed when I run it from within the "forEach" loop but cant return the values from outside the loop.
The following function should return a List of Product but returns null any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

````
Future<List<Product>> fromPlanResponse({http.Response response}) async {
    List<Product> products = [];
    if (response == null)
      return null;
    else {
      var result = json.decode(response.body);
      List items = result['items'];
      items.forEach((product) async {
        final String productId = product['id'];
        final String name = product['item']['name'];
        final int amount = product['item']['amount'];
        final String description = product['item']['description'];
        final Subscription subscription =
            await _subscription.getSubscriptions(productId: productId);
        products.add(Product(
          productId: productId,
          subscription: subscription,
          productName: name,
          description: description,
          amount: amount,
        ));
        print(products); // prints the products here
        // return products; this return does not work
      });
    }
    print("products are " + products.toString()); // this prints []
    return products; // this return []
  }```

Output for the above code

[I/flutter (14906): products are []
I/flutter (14906): []
I/flutter (14906): []

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<List<Product>> 
lib/…/profile/subsciption_screen_razorpay.dart:46
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14906): [Instance of 'Product']
I/flutter (14906): [Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product']][1]][1]
````

Comment: The error you are getting is not from the fromPlanResponse...It is rather from your FutureBuilder code...kinldly add it

Comment: The error is because future builder is getting a null value from this function so If the list of products are returned the future builder doesn't throw this error I checked!

Answer (score 0):

You should not return inside the `forEach` loop. Return after. Like this

```
Future<List<Product>> fromPlanResponse({http.Response response}) async {
    List<Product> products = [];
    if (response == null)
      return null;
    else {
      var result = json.decode(response.body);
      List items = result['items'];
      items.forEach((product) async {
        final String productId = product['id'];
        final String name = product['item']['name'];
        final int amount = product['item']['amount'];
        final String description = product['item']['description'];
        final Subscription subscription = await_subscription.getSubscriptions(productId: productId);
        products.add(Product(
          productId: productId,
          subscription: subscription,
          productName: name,
          description: description,
          amount: amount,
        ));
        print(products); // prints the products here
      });
    }
    return products;
  }
```

This way, all the **Products** would have been added to the list before returning